# Calling MATLAB from C++ errors: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-compiler

I encounter several errors when calling my MATLAB function from C++. The main idea is: firstly compile a MATLAB function and generate DLL file, and then include .h and .lib files in C++. Finally, write .cpp to test and call the function. Here's my detailed steps and please tell me where I'm wrong.

(Using MATLAB 2012b and Visual C++ 2008, Windows 7 64-bit)

**In MATLAB:**

1. `mbuild -setup` and `mex -setup` to set Visual Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 as the compiler.
2. Create `MyAdd.m` in folder `C:\Users\WangYudong\Documents\MATLAB\MyAdd_M` and the function is like:

   ```
   function [c] = MyAdd(a, b)
   c = a + b;
   ```
3. `mcc -W cpplib:libMyAdd -T link:lib MyAdd` to compile `MyAdd.m` and generate several files including `libMyAdd.dll`, `libMyAdd.h`, `libMyAdd.lib` and other files.

**In C++**

1. Select **VC++ Directories** → **Include files** to add `E:\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\include`.
2. Select **VC++ Directories** → **Library files** to add
   `E:\MATLAB\R2012b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft` and
   `C:\Users\WangYudong\Documents\MATLAB\MyAdd_M`.
3. Select **Linker** → **Input** → **Additional Dependencies** to add new entries:

   ```
   mclmcr.lib
   mclmcrrt.lib
   libmx.lib
   libmat.lib
   libMyAdd.lib
   ```
4. Create a new `MyAdd_test.cpp` and put `libMyAdd.dll`, `libMyAdd.h` and `libMyAdd.lib` in the same folder. Add `libMyAdd.h` in **Header Files**, `libMyAdd.h` and `libMyAdd.lib` in **Resource Files**.

Code of `MyAdd_test.cpp` is like:

```
#include "mclmcr.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"
#include "libMyAdd.h"

int main() {   
    double a = 6;
    double b = 9;
    double c;
    // initialize lib
    if( !libMyAddInitialize()) {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize libMyAdd!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // allocate space
    mwArray mwA(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwArray mwB(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);
    mwArray mwC(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS);  
    // set data
    mwA.SetData(&a, 1);
    mwB.SetData(&b, 1);
    // use function: MyAdd
    MyAdd(1, mwC, mwA, mwB);
    // get data
    c = mwC.Get(1, 1);
    printf("c is %f\n", c); 

    // terminate the lib
    libMyAddTerminate();   
    // terminate MCR
    mclTerminateApplication();
    return 0;
}
```

At last, the result is

```
Compiling...
MyAdd_test.cpp
Linking...
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mclTerminateApplication_proxy referenced in function _main
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libMyAddTerminate referenced in function _main
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl MyAdd(int,class mwArray &,class mwArray const &,class mwArray const &)" (__imp_?MyAdd@@YAXHAAVmwArray@@ABV1@1@Z) referenced in function _main
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _libMyAddInitialize referenced in function _main
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mclGetMatrix referenced in function "public: __thiscall mwArray::mwArray(unsigned int,unsigned int,enum mxClassID,enum mxComplexity)" (??0mwArray@@QAE@IIW4mxClassID@@W4mxComplexity@@@Z)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mclcppGetLastError referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl mwException::raise_error(void)" (?raise_error@mwException@@SAXXZ)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _mclcppCreateError referenced in function "public: __thiscall mwException::mwException(void)" (??0mwException@@QAE@XZ)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ref_count_obj_addref referenced in function "public: __thiscall mwException::mwException(class mwException const &)" (??0mwException@@QAE@ABV0@@Z)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ref_count_obj_release referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall mwException::~mwException(void)" (??1mwException@@UAE@XZ)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _error_info_get_message referenced in function "public: virtual char const * __thiscall mwException::what(void)const " (?what@mwException@@UBEPBDXZ)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _array_ref_getV_int referenced in function "public: class mwArray __cdecl mwArray::GetPromoted(unsigned int,...)" (?GetPromoted@mwArray@@QAA?AV1@IZZ)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _array_ref_set_numeric_mxDouble referenced in function "public: void __thiscall mwArray::SetData(double *,unsigned int)" (?SetData@mwArray@@QAEXPANI@Z)
MyAdd_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _array_ref_get_numeric_mxDouble referenced in function "public: __thiscall mwArray::operator double(void)const " (??BmwArray@@QBENXZ)
C:\Users\WangYudong\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MyAdd_C\Debug\MyAdd_C.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals
```

---

Actually, the work above is my test to call a custom MATLAB function from C++. My following work is to convert a MATLAB program to C++, which contains image processing functions like `imread`, `edge`, `strel`, etc. I've tried MATLAB Coder, but it can't convert MATLAB functions. So I try the method above. **Is it an efficient way to convert those functions** or should I implement them using OpenCV?

Comment: Are you compiling all your libraries for 64-bit?

Comment: When you edit the VS library configuration, make sure you edit it for every config (Debug,Release,32,64bit). You should start "debugging" this problem by seeing the actual command that is run: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823854/how-to-show-command-line-build-options-in-visual-c-2008

Comment: @WangYudong: your problem is linking. Why not use `mbuild` to build the test program: `mbuild MyAdd_test.cpp libMyAdd.lib`. It knows how to invoke the VC++ compiler/linker with the correct flags. If you add a verbose `-v` option, you'll be able to see the actual calls

Comment: btw I think you forgot to initialize the MCR first in your code: `mclInitializeApplication`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you start, make sure you have a [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2012b/win64.html) installed. That would be Visual C++ and possibly Windows SDK if you are using VS Express edition on a 64-bit Windows. Next you need to configure MATLAB by running these steps at least once:

```
>> mex -setup
>> mbuild -setup
```

---

Now given the following simple function:

#### MyAdd.m

```
function c = MyAdd(a,b)
    c = a + b;
end
```

We want to [build](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/03/creating-c-shared-libraries-and-dlls/) a [C++ shared library](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/creating-a-shared-library-from-matlab-code.html) using the MATLAB Compiler `mcc`:

```
>> mcc -N -W cpplib:libMyAdd -T link:lib MyAdd.m -v
```

This will produce a couple of files including a header file, a DLL, and an import library:

```
libMyAdd.h
libMyAdd.dll
libMyAdd.lib
```

Next we [create a C++ program](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/c-shared-library-target-1.html) to test the above library:

#### MyAdd_test.cpp

```
#include "libMyAdd.h"

int main()
{
    // initialize MCR and lib
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0))  {
        std::cerr << "could not initialize the application" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    if(!libMyAddInitialize()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        // create input
        double a[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
        double b[] = {5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0};
        mwArray in1(2, 2, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        mwArray in2(2, 2, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
        in1.SetData(a, 4);
        in2.SetData(b, 4);

        // call function
        mwArray out;
        MyAdd(1, out, in1, in2);

        // show result
        std::cout << "in1 + in2 = " << std::endl;
        std::cout << out << std::endl;

        double c[4];
        out.GetData(c, 4);
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            std::cout << c[i] << " " << std::endl;
        }

    } catch (const mwException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    } 

    // cleanup
    libMyAddTerminate();   
    mclTerminateApplication();

    return 0;
}
```

We could compile this program right from inside MATLAB using:

```
>> mbuild MyAdd_test.cpp libMyAdd.lib -v
>> !MyAdd_test
```

---

We could also compile it ourselves using Visual Studio. We start by creating a native console application, then set the project settings as follows:

- From the menu, select "Project > Properties" and apply the settings to "All configurations" (both debug and release targets)
- Under C/C++ properties, set the "Additional Include Directories" by adding both the directory containing the generated header file `libMyAdd.h`, in addition to the directory containing MATLAB's header files:

  ```
  $matlabroot\extern\include
  ```
- Similarly under "Linker", set the "Additional Library Directories". That would be the same directory as before containing `libMyAdd.lib`, as well as in my case:

  ```
  $matlabroot\extern\lib\win32\microsoft
  ```

  Then go to "Linker > Input" and add the following inside "Additional Dependencies":

  ```
  libMyAdd.lib
  mclmcrrt.lib
  ```
- Finally under "Debugging > Environment", you might want to extend the `PATH` environment variable to include the directory containing the generated `libMyAdd.dll` file. That way you can directly hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to compile run the program directly from inside VS. This will be something like:

  ```
  PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\output\folder
  ```

If you do this kind of thing often, you could create a property sheet once, which could then be reused in other VC++ projects. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16755727/97160) for an example.

Comment: An important note: if you want to compile and use your generated DLL you MUST configure Matlab to use the Visual Studio C++ compiler through `mex` and `mbuild` setup, otherwise you got linking errors in visual studio, even if you configure it as explained in this answer